# SQL Query for update a record with null values

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I want sql query for update a record. For example there are 3 columns in my table -

Name , Address, Email

and when I update any one column other columns value should be null without set null to them. Like

```
Update tbl_Student set Name = 'XYZ' where id = 1
```

In above case only Name column should update and other column should update by null.

FYI,

As there are two many columns that I need to set null that's why I wanted some kind of query to do that. Like -

```
ID    ADDRESS      NAME      EMAIL     
1     PARK ROAD    JOHN      john@gmail.com
```

And I want to update only name and want rest of the fields should be null.Like

```
Update Table SET NAME = 'NICK' WHERE ID = 1
```

Then updated output should be -

```
ID    ADDRESS      NAME      EMAIL     
1     NULL         NICK      NULL
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here, correct me if I wrong, what you need is update the record's Name and set other to null value?

Comment: What? I mean why? Not really clear what you want to achieve. Set `address = null, email = null` maybe? or a trigger? Rephrase the question please and tell us WHY do you want it and what is wrong with updating the columns explicitly.

Comment: then you can simply delete that record and insert a new row with only one column value ( Delete from table where id=1 , Insert into table(id,name) value(1,'abc') . hope you don't want to set id=NULL here :)

Comment: Agreed with @AbdulRasheed, but I am still curious, why the OP has to set all columns to NULL?

Comment: Is it possible to add a few sample records to this question, showing us what they would look like before and after the update?  This should help clear the confusion around your requirements.

Comment: @Pawan Agrawal, have u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One quick ideea that would acomplish what you want is to have two statements:

1. one that makes null everything ( except the id ) => Put a trigger on this one which executes before the second Update statement.
2. and another one that updates the column you need with actual value.

You may reconsider the table structure to a simpler one:

```
ID | Column_Name | Column_Value
```

instead of having an enormous table with NULL columns like:

```
ID | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | ..... | COLUMN N
--------------------------------------------
2  |   NULL   |   NULL   |       | "string"
```

Comment: If you know the column to set and the name of the others, why do you want to execute 2 queries? What is the benefit of running 2 queries instead of one?

Comment: @Pred I can't bring any valid point here. Maybe he wants something generic, but not as generic.

Comment: yes you are right I need something dynamic to set column null.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
    --Case-1
If @NAME is not null
UPDATE tbl_Student
SET NAME = @NAME
    ,Address = null
    ,Email = null
WHERE id = 1
--Case-2
If @Address is not null
UPDATE tbl_Student
SET NAME = null
    ,Address = @Address
    ,Email = null
WHERE id = 1
--Case-3
If @Email is not null
UPDATE tbl_Student
SET NAME =null
    ,Address = null
    ,Email = @Email
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger for this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_UPD_STUDENT] ON [dbo].[tbl_Student]
FOR UPDATE
AS

IF UPDATE(Name) and  (inserted.name <> NULL)
 BEGIN
  Update tbl_Student set Address = NULL, Email = NULL where id = inserted.id
 END

IF UPDATE(Address) and (inserted.Address <> NULL)
 BEGIN
  Update tbl_Student set name = NULL, Email = NULL where id = inserted.id
 END

IF UPDATE(Email) and (inserted.Email <> NULL)
 BEGIN
 Update tbl_Student set name = NULL, Address = NULL where id = inserted.id
 END
```

Comment: What about recursion? Will the `UPDATE` in the trigger trigger the trigger? (I love English)

Comment: That's why i have made a and clause with all conditions. Please look at this.

Comment: Point taken. Sidenode: I've removed the comments, since the column names mentioned that they came from another query.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, delete that record and insert a new one with only the column have value within a transaction. Because, i think you don't want to set `NULL` to the column `id` (may be some other column(s) also).

Sample:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Student WHERE id = 1
INSERT INTO tbl_Student(id,Name) VALUES(1,'XYZ') --All other column will be nullable
```

Note:- If the `id` column is a `IDENTITY`, then you have to manage it with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NVC_Query nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @NVC_Query = 'UPDATE  Tour_Table
SET'

 select @NVC_Query += '
    ' + columns.name + ' = NULL ,'
from sys.tables INNER JOIN
     sys.columns
ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
WHERE tables.name = 'Your table'
  AND columns.name <> 'The only col you want to update'

SET  @NVC_Query += '
     your colum = your_val
WHERE Yourcondition'

--SELECT @NVC_Query
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @NVC_Query
```

Use dynamic SQL for what you are trying to accomplish. It will be much easier than all of the previous answers